# Value2 Number as string

Tags: excel, vba, locale

I've encountered some strange behavior. 
I often have to pass Double values as a string because I need to differ between "0" and "".

Look at this easy example: 
(I'm on a German locale, so my Decimal separator is a ",")

```
Sub TestNumbers()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Value2 = "1,6"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value2 = "1,67"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value2 = "1,678"
        .Cells(1, 4).Value = "1,6789"
    End With
End Sub
```

And now look at the Output: 
[image: Why the hell?]

Why does it omit the comma at 3 Decimal Places? It happens for `.value` and `.value2` as you can see.

Comment: Have you tried it with "1.6", "1.67", "1.678" and "1.6789"? Works on my machine (also German local). I think the problem is, that the VBA-Editor always works in English

Comment: Do you want to insert the values as number or text/string?

Comment: Yeah, that would work. The thing is, that in my program the ranges first get pulled from a range. And when I assign a string with `str = Cell.Value2` I'll get it with a ",".

Comment: don't pull number values into a string variable.

Comment: Yes but when I define my variable as Double, for example, it can't be Empty since the default state of a double is 0.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question and show the code that you are actually using. Explain your actual problem instead of that constructed one.

Comment: The Code i'm using is far to complex for this problem. It's supposed to transfer Data between Workbooks using Classes. 
But i'll try doing a minimal example of that.

Comment: Your [mcve] is unclear and doesn't reflect the problem you're trying to solve. As it stands, the answer is `.Cells(1, 1).Value2 = 1.6`, i.e. don't write a string into a cell if you mean it to contain a number. It's also unclear where and how `Double` defaulting to 0 comes into play. Cells contain a `Variant`, the `Double` is the variant subtype, only when the cell contains a number. Thus, an empty cell *does* contain `Empty` (default `Variant` value).

Answer (score 1):

VBA operates as if in a US locale. If you manually entered those items into cells in a US locale, you'd see exactly the same results, namely coercion to a number once there are sufficient digits to warrant the comma being a thousands separator.

I confess I don't really follow your logic with "I often have to pass Double values as a string because I need to differ between "0" and ""."

Comment: Well if i would simply declare the value as double and i'd pull an empty cell it still would be 0. But in my use case it's 0<>"".

Comment: @JoshK Then your code should check for empty cells before assigning them to the variable. That's not really a reason to use Strings!